# How to perform aggregation without considering certain value from a column and calculating mathematical metrics under certain condition on that

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

| Call_ID | UUID | Intent_Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | Loan_BankAccount |
| A | 234 | StopCheque |
| A | 789 | Request_Agent_phone_number |
| B | 900 | Loan_BankAccount |
| B | 787 | Request_Agent_BankAcc |

I have the above table where "**Call_ID**" means a call that has been made, "**UUID**" is a unique key for a turn in the same call (Suppose **Call A** can have multiple turns such as **123, 234, 789**(here)) and "Intent_Product" refers to the description of the query.

**The expected output is :**

| Intent_Product | Resolved_Count | Contained_Turns | Contained_Calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Loan_BankAcc | 2 | 1 | 0.5 |
| Stop_Cheque | 1 | 0 | 0 |

**Conditions :**

1. **Resolution_Count :-** Count of the total number of queries that has been resolved ( Here, for example "Loan_BankAccount" =2 , "StopCheque" = 1) (where "Intent_Product" like "Request_Agent" , have to ignored as those are not resolved)
2. **Contained_Turns :-** Count the total number of queries that has been contained, but ignore those queries which has "Intent_Product" like "Request_Agent" as the successor. ( example :- here Containment count for "Loan_BankAccount" = 1 and Stop_Cheque" = 0 )
3. **Contained_Calls :-** This would be equal to **(Contained_Turns)/(Resolution_Count)**

Comment: Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: Is there a timestamp that shows in which order Intent_Product are displayed? if not then number 2 and 3 make no sense.

Comment: There is no "timestamp" as such, the order of the UUIDs is the order that we can follow , Also, the meaning of "Contained_turn" metric is basically , if there is any "Intent_Product" value which starts with "request_agent" and is occuring right after a certain value (here, StopCheque for Call A and Loan_BankAccount for Call B) then in the overall output table the number contained turns for "StopCheque" = 0 and "Loan_BankAccount" = 1 respectively (PS: kindly refer the linked output image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
  successor AS
(
  SELECT
    your_data.*,
    LEAD(intent_product)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY call_id
            ORDER BY uuid
      )
        AS successor_intent_product
  FROM
    your_data
),
  aggregate AS
(
  SELECT
    intent_product,
    COUNT(*)   AS turns,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN successor_intent_product LIKE 'Request_Agent_%' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS no_request
  FROM
    successor
  WHERE
    intent_product NOT LIKE 'Request_Agent_%'
  GROUP BY
    intent_product
)
SELECT
  *,
  no_request * 1.0 / turns   AS ratio
FROM
  aggregate
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/TY7LhjfF

Comment: by running the above code i am getting "no_request" for "Loan_BankAccount" =0 and "StopChque"=1, where it should have been the opposite.

Comment: the count of "contained_turns" is not coming the way it should

Comment: @PrabuddhaDasgupta Made a change, including a fix to your data (uuid 900 comes after uuid 787, so I changed it to 600 to make the rows process in the order your required output implies.)